# Showing TimeStamp in dataGridView

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I've tried implementing the first suggestion from [C# Winforms DataGridView Time Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1807621/c-sharp-winforms-datagridview-time-column), i.e. showing a `DateTime` picker in a `DataGridView`.

However, when I launch the app and select a date from the `dtPicker` and then select the next row, the value disappears in the first cell where I had selected a date.

What changes are needed for the cell to keep displaying its value while creating additional rows in the `DataGridView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another solution, which solved the issue. It's much cleaner and easier to implement. The solution was in an article titled:

> Embedding Calendar (DateTimePicker) Control Into DataGridView Cell

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f68f2/embedding-calendar-datetimepicker-control-into-datagridvie586/

The code suggestions in the above article work well *for every row* in the DGV.